# SQL query in Excel takes far longer when using ? to get a cell value than with value specified in query

Tags: sql-server, performance, excel, parameters

I've written an Excel query of a SQL Server database to display results from a complex view.  The view uses a join on several tables of less than 10K records, returns about 620 rows and takes 1-4 seconds to execute.  Always.  Add a WHERE clause to limit the ID sought to a specific value, and it selects between 1 and 100 rows, depending on the ID sought, and it always executes in less than 1 second.

However, modify the WHERE clause to use ID = ?, and point it at a cell.  Now the query takes 5-30 seconds to execute if less than 30 rows are selected, 2-4 minutes if 30-50 rows are selected, 10-15 minutes if 70-100 rows are selected, and times out if more.  These times are consistent.

Why does an Excel query take longer if a cell is requested using a ? parameter rather than a given value?  And why do small queries finish fast, a little larger take longer, and "large" queries take so long?

Comment: Have you used profiler to see how different the queries are that are sent to SQL Server in each case? Once you know the queries you can check the plans. Maybe this is a case of, "doctor, it hurts when I do x?" and the doctor replies, "don't do x." :-)

Comment: The queries are "Select * from IDView where id = 631" and "Select * from IDView where ID = ?".  After the second is entered, Excel (2007) asks for a cell.

Comment: I understand what Excel is showing you, but it may be changing that second one to a string comparison leading to an implicit conversion, or worse. So seeing what Profiler sees from the SQL Server side is going to provide more information than what you see inside Excel. Note that Excel probably has *very little* if anything to do with performance, there is most certainly something different on the SQL Server side.

Comment: OK, thanks.  How do I run Profiler on the SQL Server side?  How do I get to the "SQL Server side"?

Comment: @shipr: Please update the post with the table and view definitions that are referenced in the query. Looking for column names, data types, primary/foreign key constraints, etc.

Comment: Here's an article from Books Online on how to use Profiler: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx

Comment: beargle: The question is: what would be different between ID=631 and ID=?(631).  Since the selected cell's value is the same as a different invocation of the query, why would the execution plan differ?    Aaron: Thanks for your help. Today I cannot get Server Management Studio to run so I can launch the Profiler.  When I can, I think it will help.  One question remains though: even if the problem is a string conversion or other operation that makes the query take longer, why the step function?  Why not just linear?  Because it is clearly not that.

Comment: What do you mean "cannot get SQL Server Management Studio to run"? You don't need SSMS to use Profiler (it has its own menu item under the "Microsoft SQL Server / Performance Tools" Start Menu item). The stepping could be because when you select 30 rows Excel might be issuing 30 individual queries instead of a simple `IN()` list.

Comment: Instructions for running Profiler suggested both the menu item and Server Management Studio.  But it was simply not installed.  Now that I have run it, I see that the simple value sends a SELECT statement to the server.  However, with ? and a cell value, Excel sends "exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 nchar(12)',N'SELECT * FROM IDView WHERE ID=N'631           '" and it is apparently this stored procedure that takes so long.  (Note, by the way, I am never issuing 30 queries, just expecting 30 result rows.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a 'parameter sniffing' problem. Try including the line:

```
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

at the end of your SQL query.

There is an article here explaining what parameter sniffing is: http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx

Comment: Sounds reasonable. If that's not it, I cannot see why it would take 9000 times as long...